# How to adjust the number of products in the cart without repeating the items in Firestore in Dart

Tags: flutter, dart

```
 Future addCart(CartModel _cartModel, String? uid) 
 async {
  try {
  await collectionReference
      .doc(currentuser!.uid)
      .set({'userid': currentuser!.uid, 'sellerid': uid});

  return collectionReference
      .doc(currentuser!.uid)
      .collection("OrderProduit")
      .doc(id)
      .set(_cartModel.toMap());

  // ignore: empty_catches
} catch (e) {
  return false;
}
```

}

I want to add more products to the cart without repeating them
I want an example

https://i.stack.imgur.com/VUklG.jpg

Comment: Post the code you tried first, So that people can help you from this

Comment: Yes I did I posted the code

Answer (score 0):

This is how I managed to accomplish that:

'''

```
bool checkItemInCart = false;

void addCartItens({required CartProduct cartProduct}) {
    if ((cartProducts != null) && (cartProducts!.length > 0)) {
      for (CartProduct productsInCart in cartProducts!) {
        if (productsInCart.products.id == cartProduct.products.id) {
          checkItemInCart = true;
          //Increment Quantity
          quantity += productsInCart.quantity + 1;
          //Calculate SubTotal
          subtotal = calculateSubTotal(
              price: cartProduct.products.price!, quantity: quantity);

          tempCart = CartProduct(
              userId: productsInCart.userId,
              quantity: quantity,
              subtotal: subtotal!,
              cartId: productsInCart.cartId,
              products: productsInCart.products,
              status: productsInCart.status,
              date: productsInCart.date,
              totalPrice: 0.0);
          break;
        }
      }
      if (!checkItemInCart) {
        //You have Itens in The Carts with Different Ids-. Add New Item
        subtotal = calculateSubTotal(
            price: cartProduct.products.price!, quantity: quantity);
        addProductsToCartProducts(
          cartProduct: CartProduct(
              userId: cartProduct.userId,
              quantity: cartProduct.quantity,
              subtotal: subtotal!,
              cartId: cartProduct.cartId,
              products: cartProduct.products,
              status: cartProduct.status,
              date: cartProduct.date,
              totalPrice: 0.0),
        );

        _cartService.addCartItem(cartProduct: cartProduct);
      } else {
        // Update Cart
        _cartService.updateCart(
          cartProduct: tempCart!,
        );
        checkItemInCart = false;
      }
    } else {
      subtotal = calculateSubTotal(
          price: cartProduct.products.price!, quantity: cartProduct.quantity);

      // You do not have Itens in the Carts Add one.
      addProductsToCartProducts(
        cartProduct: CartProduct(
            userId: cartProduct.userId,
            quantity: cartProduct.quantity,
            subtotal: subtotal!,
            cartId: cartProduct.cartId,
            products: cartProduct.products,
            status: cartProduct.status,
            date: cartProduct.date,
            totalPrice: 0.0),
      );

      //cartProducts = productsTmp;

      _cartService.addCartItem(cartProduct: cartProduct);
    }
    //now notify listernsš
    notifyListeners();
    //_navigationService.navigateTo(CartRoute);
  }
```

'''

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have a product with many pictures and sizes. When the user chooses, I don't want to repeat the same picture size in the product cart

Comment: I assume that if you have many picture for a single product, in means that it is an array of picture, each time a user pics one product I would increase the index of the picture array to display a new image and so on. obviously am under the assumption that you would keep track of the array size so that you do not have out of bounds length.

Comment: Let's say you have a product with multiple colors and sizes When the user adds the color and size of the product, I don't want to repeat the same color and size he chose in the cart

Comment: based on the id of the product, I would search for the productId, keep track of the current colours and size he/she chose,  then update the colours and size with the new one that you have on the list of products colours and sizes.